# Create a Matrix with conditions

Tags: matrix, sas

I am struggling to create two matrix in SAS based on certain conditions.

trying to create a 12x12 matrix in the format below:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 ............col12
1     0    0    0   ............  0
1     1    0    0   ............  0
1     1    1
0     1    1
0     0    1
1     0    0
1     1    0
1     1    1
0     1    1
0     0    1
0     0    0
0     0    0
```

and so on.

and this-

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 ............col12
 1     0    0    0   ............  0
 1     2    0    0   ............  0
 1     2    3
 0     2    3
 0     0    3
 1     0    0
 1     2    0
 1     2    3
 0     2    3
 0     0    3
 0     0    0
 0     0    0
```

and so on. Basically displays the col# instead of 1's.

I read a couple of articles online and tried Proc IML but i got an error that the procedure doesn't exist.
I tried the code below to start with but nothing. I am confused as to how should I enter the conditions.

```
data test_matrices ;
 array col(12) col1-col12;
do i=1 to 12;
 j=i-1; 
col(i)=ifn(i le 5 , 1, 0,0);
output;
end;
run;
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Jay

Comment: IML is a separate license and so you might not have it licensed/installed (That's what "does not exist" means).

Comment: Yep, I understand that. Just wanted to mention that. But is there any other way I can do this ? thanks

Comment: You also should leave off the [tag:sql] tag unless this is a SQL question.  Don't use it just to indicate that you'd be okay with a SQL solution; SAS users understand PROC SQL exists.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to start with:

- Arrays have to have a name, and unless they're temporary arrays they also need variable names (they'll take the name concatenated with the array index if you don't provide it).  So:

  array (*) 1-12;

needs to be

```
array myVars(12) col1-col12;
```

- You need two loops, one to define your 'rows' and one to work on your columns, nested.  IE, for row 1, do something 12 times, for row 2, do something 12 times.

So this:

```
do i=1 to 12;
 do j=1 to 12;
  ... do stuff ...
 end;
 output; *you had this right!  It goes in the outer loop since it defines rows.;
end;
```

- Now, you have something that lets you work on just one cell.  So you're on cell (i,j); what rule defines what should go there?  Figure out that logic, and then set myvars[j] to that value.  You can't operate on the 'i' parameter, but instead that's going to just define how often you output.

Ie, this:

```
myvars[j] = i;
```

That's not correct, but figure out what is correct and assign that to myvars[j].

Comment: Thanks Joe ! I didn't added another loop do j=1 to 12 because then it creates 144 rows.I have updated the code in my question above. I am at a stage where I can populate 1 and 0 but still not able to get the condition right where in i can have 2 1s 0 and then 2 1's.

Comment: The output needs to be in the *outer* loop.  You still need two loops, though, unless your criteria for setting the column value to 1 is more straightforward - you never explain what that criteria is.

Comment: THE criteria for the first matrix is for col1,row1 value should be 1

Comment: THE criteria for the first matrix is for Matrix(x,y) if x=y then that would be the first 1 for that column. This will be followed by a 1 0 and then 1 and 1. The first example mentioned above shows that. So the pattern should be 1 1 0 1 1 for each column and the first 1 starts when x=y. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That doesn't match what you have in the question, so, no.  You have 1,1,1,0,0,1,1 there.

Comment: For example it's a hour matrix where you work 3 hrs and then take a 1 hr break and then work for 3 hrs and then stop.

Comment: sorry for the confusion but it would be 3 1's and then 0 and then 3 1's.

Comment: So figure out how to code that in programming logic for a single cell of the matrix.  Given cell (i,j), what relationship between i and j defines what value should be in that cell?  You can put it in one equation, or if needed several conditions (if ... else if ... else if ...).  You also should consider what happens for column 11 and 12 - do the other hours 'overflow' into the top (so for 11, is [1,11] a 1 or a 0?).